# My cat has strange scabs in her ear

Tags: cats, health, injury

[image]

My cat has these scabs in one of her ears and she recently fought one of my other cats (it was play fighting but it was pretty rough) so it might have gotten jacked up from that but I want to be more sure. she also has a small wound at the base of her ear. She’s also acting strange and she’s sneezing quite a bit. Thanks for any information regarding my cats jacked up ear.

Comment: the wound and scabs do not look serious but the acting strange and sneezing makes me think a visit to your vet is needed to find the cause of this,i do not think it is possible to give you a definite answer over the net for this.so i suggest you take her to the vet and get her a check-up,you might want her to get vaccsines and get her dewormed at the same time.